# New relic installation error: Our installation process has changed, please see https:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, newrelic

I had a new relic in project and it was work fine.
I want to update NewRelic and I first removed old framework (show in finder > delete > and delete from xCode project).
Then I copied new New Relic to framework folder but after I clean and build project I get error:

> Our installation process has changed, please see
>   https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/ios-1-upgrade

I have tried again and again but always get this error.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you didn't add all of the required configuration for New Relic as listed here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/ios-installation-and-configuration#configuration

Add to your build phases:

CoreTelephony.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

libz.dylib

In your [app_name]-Prefix.pch project file (generally found in the "Supporting Files" folder) include the New Relic header:
`#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h>`

In your AppDelegate.m file add this call as the first line of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
`[NewRelicAgent startWithApplicationToken:@"<your app token>"];`

Clean and build your build folder, by holding down 'option' and going to the 'product' drop-down in Xcode. ([See the screenshot here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s273/sh/8fae2d27-a937-4b55-b0b0-98e77daaa6fa/eac031d80ee10ea41c262c2b056fa99f))

If it's still not working, you'll probably need to get in touch with New Relic at support.newrelic.com

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue for a while, even though I followed every step, and then I discovered this:

In -Prefix.pch I used

```
#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent.h>
```

While I should've used the new (not appearing in auto-complete):

```
#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h>
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: I kid you not. I have not been able to solve this issue for over a year and had stopped using New Relic though I always wanted to get it back. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use new relic a month ago with my new app.  Turns out that it's not compatible with the latest iphone architecture, meaning that any app using it will probably not pass apple validation.  A email from support told me that they were working on the problem but did not have a date for completion.

Comment: This is configuration issue. I use New Relic in my app it's on the store (IOS7). Did you have similar issue like me maybe?

Comment: The latest version of the New Relic for Mobile Apps iOS SDK has support for arm64 architecture. I'll be emailing everybody who asked Support about this later in the week, but for now an upgrade to 3.184 will get you working.

Comment: Just wanted to add that our app was just approved with NewRelic for app store. So I did not experience the issue Derick F mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, for me it was because I was not paying attention.
When importing the header file to Prefix.pch it autocompleted NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent.h and I did not notice it till after a few tries.

But that was what broke my build.